# ImportError: cannot import name 'SafeUnicode'

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following import for SafeUnicode

```
from django.utils.safestring import SafeUnicode

class FightChoice(TimeStampedModel):

    def __unicode__(self):
            return SafeUnicode('<strong>{} pts</strong> if <strong>{}</strong> ends the fight by <strong>{}</strong>'.format(
                self.points, self.fighter.name, self.howitended.name
            ))
```

WHen I run the server locally it runs with no issue but on my production server I get

> File "/home/ymorin007/webapps/mmaprophet_com/src/fights/models.py",
>   line 2, in 
>       from django.utils.safestring import SafeUnicode ImportError: cannot import name 'SafeUnicode'

Any ideas what could be the issue?

Comment: What django versions do you have locally and on production?

Comment: 1.6.5 prod and 1.7c1 local

Comment: This might be about this class not being in Django 1.6.

Comment: I've installed the same version on both and still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mark a string as safe, you may like using `mark_safe(string)` which you can import as following:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
```

Has been working with Django 1.4 to 1.6, and seems fine in my local stable/1.7.x setup.

```
return mark_safe("Your text")
```